# How to use a thermal printer on a Chromebook?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, printer, chromebook, google-chrome-os

[image]

If I test it using an application called Test Bluetooth Printer which I downloaded from the Play Store, it works, but if I use the Google Chrome browser on my Chromebook, it doesn't detect my thermal printer, even when I try to connect it with a cable, my Chromebook instead asks for further configuration, and I finally configured it with all the options in configuration but still doesn't work.

I'm confused about how to connect a thermal printer on a Chromebook with a cable but my Chromebook asks for printer configuration.

Maybe someone has experience with Chromebooks or has already tried it?

All suggestions and answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may well need a manufacturer driver that is not available under ChromeOS. That's how things are sometimes. Just because one program can "see" the device does not mean your computer has enough information to **use** it. You will have to contact the manufaacturer to ask if they have drivers.